# Как можно найти открытое окно браузера из другого открытого окна?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Запускаю две странички на разных экранах. Странички с одного домена, в обеих могу дописать все что понадобиться.

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="https://host/first.html" --window-position=0,0 --kiosk --user-data-dir=c:/monitor1
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="https://host/second.html" --window-position=-1280,0 --kiosk --user-data-dir=c:/monitor2
```

Теперь хочу сделать `???.postMessage("some mess", "*");` но не знаю как найти окно в которое посылать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать широковещательный канал передачи данных `BroadcastChannel`

```
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('nameChannel');

channel.postMessage('some message');

channel.onmessage = function (ev) { 
  console.log(ev.data); 
}

channel.close();
```

И небольшая демка на CodePen: [в первом окне](https://codepen.io/rishabhsrao/pen/ddNaXB) отсылаешь, и [во втором](https://codepen.io/rishabhsrao/pen/NydoRp) принимаешь сообщения

Comment: запускаю 2 окна обмен идет, но в режиме KIOSK не реагирует

Comment: --user-data-dir=c:/monitor1 и --user-data-dir=c:/monitor2